# Show that following modules are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

> I have $M=\mathbb{Z^2/\langle(-2,5)\rangle}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module and have to show that it is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have found an isomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z^2}$ which sends $(-2,5)$ to $(0,1)$ and $(1,-2)$ to $(1,0)$. Can I say that $f$ induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z^2}/\langle(-2,5)\rangle\rightarrow\mathbb{Z^2}/\langle(0,1)\rangle$ and then conclude that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

I could say that if $\langle(-2,5)\rangle$ is the kern of $f$ and $\mathbb{Z^2}/\langle(0,1)\rangle$ the image. Why is this the case, and how can I then conclude that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 3):

If $f:G\to G$ is a module automorphism and $H$ is a submodule of $G$, then $G/H\simeq G/f(H)$.

In your case the automorphism is $f(a,b)=(5a+2b,2a+b)$ and then $$\mathbb Z^2/\langle(-2,5)\rangle\simeq \mathbb Z^2/\langle(0,1)\rangle.$$
But $\langle(0,1)\rangle=\{0\}\times\mathbb Z$. Now $$\mathbb Z^2/\{0\}\times\mathbb Z\simeq\mathbb Z/\{0\}\times\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z\simeq\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: "If f:G→G is a module automorphism and H is a submodule of G, then G/H≃G/f(H)." Is this a theorem? Does  it follow from the homomorphism theorem for modules with kernel and images?

Comment: Yes, it is a theorem and follows from the fundamental theorem of isomorphism for modules: the map $G\to G/f(H)$ given by $x\mapsto f(x)+f(H)$ is surjective and its kernel is $H$.

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps better to look for a homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\ker f=\langle(-2,5)\rangle$.

You need to choose $f((1,0))=a$ and $f((0,1))=b$ and a requirement is that
$$
f((-2,5))=-2f((1,0))+5f((0,1))=-2a+5b=0
$$
Well, a first attempt would be $a=5$, $b=2$.

Suppose now $(x,y)\in\ker f$, which means $ax+by=0$, hence $5x+2y=0$. In particular $5x\equiv0\pmod2$, so $x=2u$, and $2y\equiv0\pmod{5}$, so $y=5v$ and we need $10(u+v)=0$,so $u=-v$ and therefore
$$
(x,y)=(-2v,5v)=v(-2,5)
$$
OK, $\ker f=\langle(-2,5)\rangle$. Now, is $f$ surjective?

Comment: Would the image be $\mathbb{Z}$? Then we should write every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ from ⟨(−2,5)⟩?

Comment: @Annalisa What's $f(2,1)$? By the way, do you know about Bézout's identity?

Answer (score 1):

As you say $\mathbb{Z}^2/\langle(0,1)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. This is pretty clear; you send $(a,b)\mapsto a$ and this is clearly surjective but it's also injective as the kernel of this map is the image of $(0,b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2/\langle(0,1)\rangle$. $(0,b)$ is in the ideal that we are quotienting out by so it's the zero element in the quotient.

Now the crux of the question is to show that the first map you wrote down is an isomorphism. Here you want to write down your $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map in terms of its matrix (with respect to a basis) and show that the determinant is $\pm 1$.
Convince yourself that this is indeed the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2\\-2& 5\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$ with respect to the standard basis. (You can think of as $A\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and likewise for the other vector. Now piece these two parts to write down a matrix for $A$.)

Comment: do you mean the first map $f$? I defined it as a map that sends (-2,5) to (0,1) and (1,-2) to (1,0) and I can write all other elements as linear combinations of these, therefore an isomorphism? What about the induced isomorphism from f , say g which is Z2/⟨(−2,5)⟩→Z2/⟨(0,1)⟩  ? why would that be an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Alterntively, a key observation is that $(-2,5)$ is part of a basis for $\mathbb Z^2$. Indeed, $\{ (-2,5), (-1,2) \}$ is a basis (found by the extended Euclidean algorithm, since $\gcd(-2,5)=1$). Then
$$
\frac{\mathbb Z^2}{\langle(-2,5)\rangle}
=
\frac{\mathbb Z (-2,5) \oplus \mathbb Z(-1,2)}{\mathbb Z (-2,5) \oplus 0\hskip11mm}
\cong
\mathbb Z(-1,2)
\cong
\mathbb Z
$$